# Django. Add new property ForeignKey to User model existing model: OperationalError

Tags: django, database, sqlite

I have existing model which was created before, and I would like to add ForeignKey property to User model, when I run migrations command, I take following errors (the full trace in images):
[image]
[image]
The model:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    birthday = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    fromdate = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    appdate = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    district = models.ForeignKey(District, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    address = models.TextField(default='')
    gender = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    occupation = models.ForeignKey(Occupation, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    # it is extra field for patient to prevent from deleting them
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

In addition, in an another project, I have done the same action without facing any difficulties.

Comment: Show the _full_ stack trace of the error.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I have added the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Not a photo! Add it as _text_ formatted as code. Plus that still doesn't appear to be the _full_ traceback,

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, I am sorry and thank your attention, I can not add all trace errors because of the stackoverflow doesn't allow me add such as too many code. But I have done by turning of one url from the main url. In the trace errors, there is one link to that url: `File"D:\Nuu\AI\Researchs\Tuberculosis\programs\TuberculosisSystem\backend\django\src\tuberculosis\urls.py", line 10, in <module> path('api/', include('ai.urls'))`. But why I must do so, I do not know.